# How do I use a static Handler together with Services/Activities?

Tags: android, service

So apparently `Handlers` should be declared static or they could leak their outer class (and the application context along with it). This obviously limits what you can do with the `Handler`, and I'm wondering if what I want to do is actually possible. Take a look at this piece of code:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private int counter;

    private static final Handler handler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // Increment counter here
        }

    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        counter = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

The static handler can't hold a reference to the service, and thus a simple `counter++` inside `handleMessage()` wouldn't work. Is there a way to check if the service is running and obtain a reference to it?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407943/this-handler-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur-incominghandler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [WeakReference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) to protect your Service from leaking. But actually `Handler` in your code looks redundant. Both `onCreate` and `onStartCommand` are called from the UI thread so you can safely increase your `counter` without additional synchronization.

If you really need to access `counter` from different threads use [AtomicInteger](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead of `int` for it. It will be more simpler than using `Handler` and you will gain more performance.

Comment: Thanks, the code I gave is sort of a simplified version of my problem. In reality, the Handler handles callbacks from a worker thread, so I do not know when the Integer should be updated, but AtomicInteger seems to elegantly solve this problem, thanks a lot.