# How to get the activity to wait before jumping to the next activity on its own in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, wait

I want to create an activity that opens when I start my app, wait some time and jumps to the next activity without the user pressing anything.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Thread thread = new Thread();
    thread.start();
}

public class waitSeconds extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        Log.i("MyActivity", "MyClass");
        try {
            wait(300);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, main_window.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As it seems that it is never going to the "run" method.

How can I do this?

Comment: You would have to call `Thread thread = new waitSeconds();` in order for your `waitSeconds` class to ever be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include this in your Activity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SplashHandler handler=new SplashHandler();
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = 0;
    handler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 3000);

}

private class SplashHandler extends Handler {

            public void handleMessage(Message msg)
              {
                switch (msg.what)
                {
                default:
                case 0:
                  super.handleMessage(msg);

                  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,main_window.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
                  MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
              }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! its working great!
but its saying "This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur"  how can i fix this?\

Comment: Implement this as your MainActivity

Comment: thats exactly what i did. still the same problem.

Comment: It does work fine for the most part, but their is a reason it's warning you. I had the same problem and eventually it created a "memory leak". See this answer on how to properly implement a static handler, it's pretty easy and will save headaches later on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407943/this-handler-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur-incominghandler

Answer (score 1):

### you need something like this:

```java
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                try {
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);

                    Thread.sleep(2000);

                    startActivity(i);

                    finish();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();

    }

}
```