# Android Handler Chain NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-handler

I'm trying to create communication between `Activity` - `Service` - `Thread` by `Handlers`. `Activity` starts a  `Service` that starts a `Thread`. `Thread` sends request to the server, waits answer and resend it to `Service` by `Handler` (work fine). But when i have try to send message from `Service`'s `Handler` to `Activity` app closed with NullPointerException. What am i do wrong?

Handler code based on [Android Handler changing WeakReference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221593/android-handler-changing-weakreference)

My Activity

```
public class ActivityLogin extends Activity{

    public static LoginHandler loginHandler = null;

    public static class LoginHandler extends Handler {

        private WeakReference<ActivityLogin> target = null;

        LoginHandler(ActivityLogin target) {
            this.target = new WeakReference<ActivityLogin>(target);
        }

        public void setTarget(ActivityLogin target) {
            this.target.clear();
            this.target = new WeakReference<ActivityLogin>(target);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            ActivityLogin activity = this.target.get();
            if(activity == null) return;

            String response = msg.getData().getString("RESPONSE");
            System.err.println("RESPONSE "+response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("TAG","---------------------APP STARTED---------------------");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_login);

        if(loginHandler == null) loginHandler = new LoginHandler(this);
        else loginHandler.setTarget(this);
    }

    public void onLogin(View v){

        JsonUser user = new JsonUser();
        user.login = "Name";
        user.password = "Pazzword";
        user.device = "4567-753-5768-2343";

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,ComService.class);
        intent.putExtra("DATA_KEY", new Gson().toJson(user));

        this.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

My Service

```
public class ComService extends Service {

    public static ServiceHandler serviceHandler = null;

    public static class ServiceHandler extends Handler {

        private WeakReference<ComService> target = null;
        ServiceHandler(ComService target) {
            this.target = new WeakReference<ComService>(target);
        }

        public void setTarget(ComService target) {
            this.target.clear();
            this.target = new WeakReference<ComService>(target);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            //ComService service = this.target.get();
            //Process message (msg) and resend to activity
            ActivityLogin.loginHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if(serviceHandler == null) serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler(this);
        else serviceHandler.setTarget(this);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        String message = intent.getStringExtra("DATA_KEY");

        new SendData("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27019/WebService.svc/login",message);
        stopSelf(startId);
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }
}
```

My Thread

```
public class SendData extends Thread {

    private String requestUrl;
    private String message;

    public SendData(String requestUrl, String message){
        super();
        this.requestUrl = requestUrl;
        this.message = message;
        this.start();
    }

    public void run(){

        String serverResponse = request();
        if(serverResponse == null) return;

        System.err.println(serverResponse);

        Message msg = new Message();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("RESPONSE", serverResponse);
        msg.setData(bundle);

        ComService.serviceHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    private String request(){...}//if need, i can post request code too
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
04-15 18:36:35.292  24524-24524/com.example.test E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-15 18:36:35.332  24524-24524/com.example.test D/TAG﹕ ---------------------APP STARTED---------------------
04-15 18:36:35.462  24524-24524/com.example.test D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
04-15 18:36:35.462  24524-24524/com.example.test D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
04-15 18:36:35.462  24524-24524/com.example.test D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
04-15 18:36:35.492  24524-24524/com.example.test D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-15 18:36:36.442  24554-24554/com.example.test:background E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-15 18:36:36.682  24554-24567/com.example.test:background W/System.err﹕ {"status":{"success":false,"message":"some_text"},"result":null}
04-15 18:36:36.682  24554-24554/com.example.test:background D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-15 18:36:36.682  24554-24554/com.example.test:background W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41712300)
04-15 18:36:36.682  24554-24554/com.example.test:background E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.test.ComService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(ComService.java:31)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

AndroidManifext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.test"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
        <activity android:name=".ActivityLogin"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".ComService"
                 android:exported="false"
                 android:process=":background"
        />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post the complete stacktrace of the exception

Comment: add stacktrace of the exception and manifest

Comment: That's not the way you are supposed to implement service to activity communication. Have a look at messages or read about service binding.

Comment: Very interesting! You can do Activity-Service-Thread-Activity, but not Activity-Service-Thread-Service-Activity.

Answer (score 0):

In conclusion, i deleted `Service` from my application. Android `Service` is cancer tumor, threads without benefits. It's just my opinion.