# "Handler class should be static or leaks might occur" - Handler has references to main activity variables

Tags: variables, android-activity, reference, static, handler

Android: i have a Handler class defined inside my activity and i get the warning "Handler class should be static or leaks might occur" with the following code:

```
    Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {
      // @Override 
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        try {
            ... accessing variables defined at the activity level
            ... doing something very important
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg)
      }
    }
```

However, the problem is that my message Handler has references to main activity variables, so i cannot make it static. How in my case can i get rid of that warning (in correct manner)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {
      // @Override 
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        try {
            ... accessing variables defined at the activity level
            ... doing something very important
        }
      }
    }
```

To

```
Handler mIncomingHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
    }
});
```

Refercnce:
[This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur: IncomingHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407943/this-handler-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur-incominghandler)

Comment: Handler(Handler.Callback()) deprecated from API 30, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65047948/handlerhandler-callback-is-deprecated