# My Runner using a Handler is not working on android

Tags: java, android, random, handler, runner

Here's what I got so far guys, this is my app, all it does is display a digital clock and move the clock to a new part of the screen every 30 seconds, but it doesn't actually do that last part, here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {         
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
};
Handler handler = new Handler() {       
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {            
        //change the text position here         
        this.postDelayed(runnable , 30000);
        }
    }; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.digitalClock);  
    Random r = new Random();

    Thread thread =new Thread(runnable );
    thread.start();

    int x = r.nextInt(350 - 100);
    int y = r.nextInt(800 - 100);

    textView.setX(x);  
    textView.setY(y);
    }
```

I just cant seem to get this to work, been scanning the internet for about a week now. I think it's got something to do with the "New Thread" but not too sure what.

Comment: does it throw any exception/error?

Comment: Nope nothing
Actually, yes it does mention something about my Handler class should be static or leaks might occur which is underlined in Yellow.

Comment: technically, you are not supposed to use a new (non-ui) thread to manipulate ui elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to create an extra `Runnable` instance or your own thread.

In the `onCreate` method, all you should do is call `setContentView` and send an empty message to the handler.

In the `handleMessage` method of your `Handler` instance, set the X and Y of the TextView and post another empty message with a delay.

Here's an Activity that will do what you want. It uses an `AbsoluteLayout` to do the absolute positioning of the `TextView` which is deprecated, but it should demonstrate the `Handler` bits which are at the core of your question.

```
package com.scompt.so16209790;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Handler handler = new RandomMoveHandler((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view));
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }

    // Make the handler subclass static because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11408340/111777
    private static class RandomMoveHandler extends Handler {
        private final WeakReference<TextView> textViewWeakReference;

        private RandomMoveHandler(TextView textView) {
            this.textViewWeakReference = new WeakReference<TextView>(textView);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            TextView textView = textViewWeakReference.get();
            if (textView == null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "WeakReference is gone so giving up.");
                return;
            }

            int x = RANDOM.nextInt(350 - 100);
            int y = RANDOM.nextInt(800 - 100);

            Log.i(TAG, String.format("Moving text view to (%d, %d)", x, y));
            textView.setX(x);
            textView.setY(y);

            //change the text position here
            this.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 3000);
        }
    }

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
}
```

The `main` layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="0px"
    android:layout_y="0px"
    android:text="Hello World, MainActivity"
    />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: please do, this is driving me crazy.

Comment: I've updated my answer with complete code because it looks like you've been asking different versions of this same question for the past 2 weeks.

Comment: I love you, I love you, you are the dogs balls! Dude whats your website? Do you take donations?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit curious about your solution, I'd like to not use Thread in Android app, you can just trigger Handler instead.
 Here is example

> Handler handler = new Handler() {
>       @Override
>       public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
>          // your jobs
>       }
>   };

and then in activity you can just **postAtTime** method where you need.