# How to change textView (digitalClock) color on touch(screen)

Tags: java, android, colors, textview, touch

I'm making an app that just displays a clock, but I want is so that everytime a user touches the screen it changes the color of the text (from a list of preselected colors in a colors.xml file) but I haven't got a clue where to start. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here's the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Handler handler = new RandomMoveHandler((TextView) findViewById(R.id.digitalClock1));
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}

// Make the handler subclass static because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11408340/111777
private static class RandomMoveHandler extends Handler {
    private final WeakReference<TextView> textViewWeakReference;

    private RandomMoveHandler(TextView textView) {
        this.textViewWeakReference = new WeakReference<TextView>(textView);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        TextView textView = textViewWeakReference.get();
        if (textView == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "WeakReference is gone so giving up.");
            return;
        }

        int x = RANDOM.nextInt(350 - 100);
        int y = RANDOM.nextInt(800 - 100);

        Log.i(TAG, String.format("Moving text view to (%d, %d)", x, y));
        textView.setX(x);
        textView.setY(y);

        //change the text position here
        this.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 30000);
    }
}

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
```

}

and here's the layout xml:

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@color/black" >

 <DigitalClock
    android:id="@+id/digitalClock1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DigitalClock"
    android:textColor="@color/ics_blue"
    android:textSize="28sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't making deal with `DigitalClock` but I think, at first, you should reference `DigitalClock` variable, not `TextView`. And second, to intercept touch event you need to override [onTouckEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) method of your activity, it will callback everytime user touches the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow these steps

1. Use a TimerTask to.continusly show the time
2. Implement a touchlistener on that clock view

like this
view.setOnTouchListener

1. Make an array Colors like this

int[] colr={Color.BLACK,Color.BLUE};

and use random index in your touch event andset it as your color of the view