# Android: How to use a Handler handleMessage and access the reference to the MainActivity

Tags: android, android-handler

I have a service which receives a command from the Internet and launches a background thread. This thread is passed a handler from the service (the service is bounded and passed the handler) and sends a message to the handler to take a picture. I'm stuck on the implementation of the handler.

```
static Handler handler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            //TODO: Handle different types of messages
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, MainActivity.this);
        }
};
```

Questions:

- Does Handler need to be static? Without static, I get "This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur"
- Does mCamera need to be static? I've been told to make mCamera static, but why is this necessary? Is there a way to setup takePicture without making mCamera static?
- What's the proper way to pass the reference to MainActivity? Right now I get the error: "No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope"

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16071874/2359488

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make a class (Activity/Service) implement `Handler.Callback` and create a new Handler for it via `new Handler(this)`.

Comment: This did the trick as it simplifies a lot of the overhead (I don't have to pass the object, etc) compared to the other methods described in this post.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code as follows:

```
    static Handler handler = new Handler() {

            MainActivity mActivity;

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                //TODO: Handle different types of messages
                if(mActivity != null) {
                    mActivity.mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mActivity);
                }
            }
    };

    void MainActivity::onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
         ...
         handler.mActivity = this;
    }

    void MainActivity::onDestroy() {
        ...
        handler.mActivity = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good explanation why handler should be static:

[This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur: IncomingHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407943/this-handler-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur-incominghandler)

About your other question, if you make Handler static you should also make all the fields that you use inside it static.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Message](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html) member `obj` and pass the desired object to the handler.

```
static Handler handler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            //TODO: Handle different types of messages
            //TODO: handle cast exception
            final MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) msg.obj;
            final Camera camera = activity.getCamera();
            camera.takePicture(null, null, activity);
        }
};
```