# Getters and setters in metronome

Tags: android, setter, getter

I have I think simple problem which I can't fix on my own. In the code below I need to set the loudBars variable to the other class. I made the setLoudBars() but it just doesn't work. Anyone sees any solution in this?

```
public class DrumActivity extends Activity {

    private final short minBpm = 40;
    private final short maxBpm = 208;


    private short bpm = 100;
    private short noteValue = 4;
    private short beats = 4;
    private short volume;
    private short initialVolume;
    private double beatSound = 2440;
    private double sound = 6440;
    private AudioManager audio;
    private MetronomeAsyncTask metroTask;

    private Button plusButton;
    private Button minusButton;
    private TextView currentBeat;

    private Handler mHandler;

    private int loudBars = 2;
    private short silentBars = 1;

    // have in mind that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407943/this-handler-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur-incominghandler
    // in this case we should be fine as no delayed messages are queued
    private Handler getHandler() {
        return new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                String message = (String)msg.obj;
                if(message.equals("1")) {
                    currentBeat.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                }else {
                    currentBeat.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
                }
                currentBeat.setText(message);
            }
        };
    }


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drum);
        metroTask = new MetronomeAsyncTask();
        /* Set values and listeners to buttons and stuff */

        TextView eLoudBars = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eLoudBars);
        eLoudBars.setText(""+loudBars);
        TextView eSilentBars = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eSilentBars);

        Button minusLoud = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lbminus);
        minusLoud.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loudBars--;
                if(loudBars < 1)
                    loudBars = 1;
                TextView eLoudBars = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eLoudBars);
                eLoudBars.setText(""+loudBars);
                metroTask.setLoudBars(loudBars);
            }
        });

        Button plusLoud = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lbplus);
        plusLoud.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loudBars++;
                TextView eLoudBars = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eLoudBars);
                eLoudBars.setText(""+loudBars);
                metroTask.setLoudBars(loudBars);
            }
        });

        Button minusSilent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sbminus);

        Button plusSilent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sbplus);

        TextView bpmText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bps);
        bpmText.setText(""+bpm);

        TextView timeSignatureText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timesignature);
        timeSignatureText.setText(""+beats+"/"+noteValue);

        plusButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
        plusButton.setOnLongClickListener(plusListener);

        minusButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);
        minusButton.setOnLongClickListener(minusListener);

        currentBeat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentBeat);
        currentBeat.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

        Spinner beatSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.beatspinner);
        ArrayAdapter<Beats> arrayBeats =
        new ArrayAdapter<Beats>(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Beats.values());
        beatSpinner.setAdapter(arrayBeats);
        beatSpinner.setSelection(Beats.four.ordinal());
        arrayBeats.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown);
        beatSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(beatsSpinnerListener);

        Spinner noteValuesdSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.notespinner);
        ArrayAdapter<NoteValues> noteValues =
        new ArrayAdapter<NoteValues>(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, NoteValues.values());
        noteValuesdSpinner.setAdapter(noteValues);
        noteValues.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown);
        noteValuesdSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(noteValueSpinnerListener);

        audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        initialVolume = (short) audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        volume = initialVolume;

        SeekBar volumebar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.volumebar);
        volumebar.setMax(audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        volumebar.setProgress(volume);
        volumebar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(volumeListener);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public synchronized void onStartStopClick(View view) {
        Button button = (Button) view;
        String buttonText = button.getText().toString();
        if(buttonText.equalsIgnoreCase("start")) {
            button.setText(R.string.stop);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                metroTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, (Void[])null);
            else
                metroTask.execute();            
        } else {
            button.setText(R.string.start);     
            metroTask.stop();
            metroTask = new MetronomeAsyncTask();
            Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        }
    }

    private void maxBpmGuard() {
        if(bpm >= maxBpm) {
            plusButton.setEnabled(false);
            plusButton.setPressed(false);
        } else if(!minusButton.isEnabled() && bpm>minBpm) {
            minusButton.setEnabled(true);
        }       
    }

    public void onPlusClick(View view) {
        bpm++;
        TextView bpmText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bps);
        bpmText.setText(""+bpm);
        metroTask.setBpm(bpm);
        maxBpmGuard();
    }

    private OnLongClickListener plusListener = new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            bpm+=20;
            if(bpm >= maxBpm)
                bpm = maxBpm;
            TextView bpmText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bps);
            bpmText.setText(""+bpm);
            metroTask.setBpm(bpm);
            maxBpmGuard();
            return true;
        }

    };

    private void minBpmGuard() {
        if(bpm <= minBpm) {
            minusButton.setEnabled(false);
            minusButton.setPressed(false);
        } else if(!plusButton.isEnabled() && bpm<maxBpm) {
            plusButton.setEnabled(true);
        }       
    }

    public void onMinusClick(View view) {
        bpm--;
        TextView bpmText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bps);
        bpmText.setText(""+bpm);
        metroTask.setBpm(bpm);
        minBpmGuard();
    }

    private OnLongClickListener minusListener = new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            bpm-=20;
            if(bpm <= minBpm)
                bpm = minBpm;
            TextView bpmText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bps);
            bpmText.setText(""+bpm);
            metroTask.setBpm(bpm);
            minBpmGuard();
            return true;
        }

    };

    private OnSeekBarChangeListener volumeListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            volume = (short) progress;
            audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }       

    };

    private OnItemSelectedListener beatsSpinnerListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Beats beat = (Beats) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            TextView timeSignature = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timesignature);
            timeSignature.setText(""+beat+"/"+noteValue);
            metroTask.setBeat(beat.getNum());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };

    private OnItemSelectedListener noteValueSpinnerListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            NoteValues noteValue = (NoteValues) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            TextView timeSignature = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timesignature);
            timeSignature.setText(""+beats+"/"+noteValue);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
        SeekBar volumebar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.volumebar);
        volume = (short) audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        switch(keycode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN: 
                volumebar.setProgress(volume);
                break;                
        }

        return super.onKeyUp(keycode, e);
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        metroTask.stop();
//      metroTask = new MetronomeAsyncTask();
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, initialVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
        finish();    
    }

    private class MetronomeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
        Metronome metronome;

        MetronomeAsyncTask() {
            mHandler = getHandler();
            metronome = new Metronome(mHandler);
        }



        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            metronome.setBeat(beats);
            metronome.setNoteValue(noteValue);
            metronome.setBpm(bpm);
            metronome.setBeatSound(beatSound);
            metronome.setSound(sound);
            metronome.setLoudBars(loudBars);

            metronome.play();

            return null;            
        }

        public void stop() {
            metronome.stop();
            metronome = null;
        }

        public void setBpm(short bpm) {
            metronome.setBpm(bpm);
            metronome.calcSilence();
        }

        public void setBeat(short beat) {
            if(metronome != null)
                metronome.setBeat(beat);
        }

        public void setLoudBars(int loudBars) {
            if(metronome != null)
                metronome.setLoudBars(loudBars);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You might have a timing problem, but that is hard to say like that. Two questions: 1. What does not work? 2. is `metronome.play()` blocking or does the `doInBackground()` method runs through? I would add some log statements so you can see what exactly is going on.

Comment: No, timing is good. The problem lies in here that I defined number of loudBars (to 3) in DrumActivity (which is main) and the number of silentBars is in MetronomeActivity (and is set to 1) so it don't have to use get/set.

So, it reads silentBars value and goes on and on with one bar, while there should be four...