# Does long running thread result in Activity memory leaks?

Tags: android

I've written a Utilloader class which provide a loader thread that load some data from net. in my activity I start a new loader thread. The thread then update the activity via handler.post().

```
class MyActivity extends Activity
{
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initUI();
    UtilLoader.getInstance().load("url", new UtilLoad.OnLoadListener
    {
      public void onLoadSuccess(String response)
      {
         updateUI();
      }
    });
  }
}

class UtilLoader
{
  private Handler handler = new Handler();
  private UtilLoader instance = new UtilLoader();
  private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
  public interface OnLoadListener
  {
    public void onLoadSuccess(String response);
  }
  public UtilLoader getInstance()
  {
    return instance;
  }
  public load(String url, OnLoadListener onLoadListener)
  {
    executorService.submit(new Loader(url, onLoadListener));
  }
  public class Loader extends Runnable
  {
     private String url;
     private OnLoadListener onLoadListener;
     public Loader(String url, OnLoadListener onLoadListener)
     {
        this.url = url;
        this.onLoadListener = onLoadListener;
     }
     public void run()
     {
        // LOAD DATA
        handler.post(new Runnable() {        
           public void run() {
             onLoadListener.onLoadSuccess(sb.toString());
           }
        });
     }
  }
}
```

Does this way of activity updating result in memory leaks by keeping a reference to the activity? If yes how must I change it, so there is no memory leaks?

Comment: yes, if you are setting a callback i.e. updateUI() it will definitely result in memory leak by keep a reference to it thus preventing the GC from collecting it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `UtilLoader` holds a reference to the anonymous inner class which you pass in as `OnLoadListener` and this anonymous inner class in turn holds a reference to the activity.

Comment: You can for example use a service and bind and unbind your activity dynamically

Comment: a service only for loading some internal data? can I use Handler message instead?

Comment: @Ali check this if it helps http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html

Comment: Another possibility is to use Android loaders: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Comment: @Raghunandan Can I use weak reference to the activity in my code?

Comment: @Ali if your using the activity context in an inner class yes use a weak reference and make the inner class static

Answer (score 0):

yes, if you are setting a callback i.e. updateUI() it will definitely result in memory leak by keep a reference to it thus preventing the GC from collecting it.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. As long as the Looper associated with the handler has messages in the queue, it will keep a reference to the associated Activity/Service. This could be a problem for long-running operations. See this thread for more:

[This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur: IncomingHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407943/this-handler-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur-incominghandler)