# What's the diference between the two ways of initializing Handler?

Tags: android, android-handler

I am confuse about the following two ways to initialize the Handler. **What's the difference ?**

**1. First way:**

```
class MyFirstActivity extends Activity {
    class Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    ...
}
```

**2. Second way:**

```
class MySecondActivity extends Activity {

    private MyHandler mHandler;

    @Oerride
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        mHandler = new MyHandler(getMainLooper());
    }

    private final class MyHandler extends Handler {
        public MyHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper, null, true);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Note:
I know there is the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html):

> ```
> Handler() - Default constructor associates this handler with the Looper for the current thread.
> If this thread does not have a looper, this handler won't be able to receive messages so an exception is thrown.
> and
> Handler(Looper looper) - Use the provided Looper instead of the default one.
> ```

It means I want to know more, like

1. **when quit, are there some special operations to do?**
2. **Which way is better (or More efficient)?**

Thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Handler (Looper looper)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#Handler%28android.os.Looper%29) constructor (**second way**) is used when creating `Handler` from threads, which do not have default looper, or when you want the handler to run actions on a different thread than your own.

In your "second way" example there is no need to use this type of constructor,  the [default one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#Handler%28%29) will do the same. And as the Activity `constructor` is invoked on the same thread as `onCreate(..)` method, two possible initializations ("first" and "second way") of `Handler` are totally equal.

UPD: make sure [not to create inner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407943/this-handler-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur-incominghandler) Handler class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! About the **"not to create inner Handler class"** issue, I think if I remove the messages when pause the Activity or quit the app, it won't happen the leak, right ?

Comment: Right, but to be on the safe side use [this solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/1aPZXZG6kWk/lIYDavGYn5UJ)

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

> Handler() - Default constructor associates this handler with the
> Looper for the current thread.
>
> If this thread does not have a looper, this handler won't be able to receive messages so an exception is thrown.
>
> and
>
> Handler(Looper looper) - Use the provided Looper instead of the default one.

Here **Looper** is Class used to run a message loop for a thread. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html)

Answer (score -1):

It's [documented here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). Basically second example explicitly tries to get app's main looper, while first one leaves this to the Handler's constructor:

> Default constructor associates this handler with the Looper for the
>   current thread.

Since your both classes are Activities, there's no difference in this particular case.