# App stops after certain button click

Tags: android, android-activity

I've (legally) copied and pasted some project code from an app called beatkeeper into my own app. I wanted to implement a metronome.
The app beatkeeper on itself works fine but as I soon as I copy the code and run my own app, it's stops working the moment I click the start/stop button...

```
    04-07 09:25:05.126: E/AndroidRuntime(2708): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-07 09:25:05.126: E/AndroidRuntime(2708): Process: nl.ruudjanssenmusicservices.desaxofoonapp, PID: 2708
    04-07 09:25:05.126: E/AndroidRuntime(2708): java.lang.NullPointerException
    04-07 09:25:05.126: E/AndroidRuntime(2708):     at nl.ruudjanssenmusicservices.desaxofoonapp.MetronomeActivity$6.handleMessage(MetronomeActivity.java:54)
    04-07 09:25:05.126: E/AndroidRuntime(2708):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    04-07 09:25:05.126: E/AndroidRuntime(2708):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    04-07 09:25:05.126: E/AndroidRuntime(2708):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    04-07 09:25:05.126: E/AndroidRuntime(2708):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-07 09:25:05.126: E/AndroidRuntime(2708):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    04-07 09:25:05.126: E/AndroidRuntime(2708):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    04-07 09:25:05.126: E/AndroidRuntime(2708):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    04-07 09:25:05.126: E/AndroidRuntime(2708):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Source main activity:

```
package nl.ruudjanssenmusicservices.desaxofoonapp;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MetronomeActivity extends Activity {

    private final short minBpm = 40;
    private final short maxBpm = 208;

    private short bpm = 100;
    private short noteValue = 4;
    private short beats = 4;
    private short volume;
    private short initialVolume;
    private double beatSound = 2440;
    private double sound = 6440;
    private AudioManager audio;
    private MetronomeAsyncTask metroTask;

    private Button plusButton;
    private Button minusButton;
    private TextView currentBeat;

    private Handler mHandler;

    // have in mind that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407943/this-handler-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur-incominghandler
    // in this case we should be fine as no delayed messages are queued
    private Handler getHandler() {
        return new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                String message = (String)msg.obj;
                if(message.equals("1"))
                    currentBeat.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                else
                    currentBeat.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
                currentBeat.setText(message);
            }
        };
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        metroTask = new MetronomeAsyncTask();
        /* Set values and listeners to buttons and stuff */

        TextView bpmText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bps);
        bpmText.setText(""+bpm);

        TextView timeSignatureText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timesignature);
        timeSignatureText.setText(""+beats+"/"+noteValue);

        plusButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
        plusButton.setOnLongClickListener(plusListener);

        minusButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);
        minusButton.setOnLongClickListener(minusListener);

      //  currentBeat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentBeat);
        //currentBeat.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

        Spinner beatSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.beatspinner);
        ArrayAdapter<Beats> arrayBeats =
        new ArrayAdapter<Beats>(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Beats.values());
        beatSpinner.setAdapter(arrayBeats);
        beatSpinner.setSelection(Beats.four.ordinal());
        arrayBeats.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown);
        beatSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(beatsSpinnerListener);

        Spinner noteValuesdSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.notespinner);
        ArrayAdapter<NoteValues> noteValues =
        new ArrayAdapter<NoteValues>(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, NoteValues.values());
        noteValuesdSpinner.setAdapter(noteValues);
        noteValues.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown);
        noteValuesdSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(noteValueSpinnerListener);

        audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        initialVolume = (short) audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        volume = initialVolume;

        SeekBar volumebar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.volumebar);
        volumebar.setMax(audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        volumebar.setProgress(volume);
        volumebar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(volumeListener);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public synchronized void onStartStopClick(View view) {
        Button button = (Button) view;
        String buttonText = button.getText().toString();
        if(buttonText.equalsIgnoreCase("start")) {
            button.setText(R.string.stop);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                metroTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, (Void[])null);
            else
                metroTask.execute();            
        } else {
            button.setText(R.string.start);     
            metroTask.stop();
            metroTask = new MetronomeAsyncTask();
            Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        }
    }

    private void maxBpmGuard() {
        if(bpm >= maxBpm) {
            plusButton.setEnabled(false);
            plusButton.setPressed(false);
        } else if(!minusButton.isEnabled() && bpm>minBpm) {
            minusButton.setEnabled(true);
        }       
    }

    public void onPlusClick(View view) {
        bpm++;
        TextView bpmText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bps);
        bpmText.setText(""+bpm);
        metroTask.setBpm(bpm);
        maxBpmGuard();
    }

    private OnLongClickListener plusListener = new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            bpm+=20;
            if(bpm >= maxBpm)
                bpm = maxBpm;
            TextView bpmText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bps);
            bpmText.setText(""+bpm);
            metroTask.setBpm(bpm);
            maxBpmGuard();
            return true;
        }

    };

    private void minBpmGuard() {
        if(bpm <= minBpm) {
            minusButton.setEnabled(false);
            minusButton.setPressed(false);
        } else if(!plusButton.isEnabled() && bpm<maxBpm) {
            plusButton.setEnabled(true);
        }       
    }

    public void onMinusClick(View view) {
        bpm--;
        TextView bpmText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bps);
        bpmText.setText(""+bpm);
        metroTask.setBpm(bpm);
        minBpmGuard();
    }

    private OnLongClickListener minusListener = new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            bpm-=20;
            if(bpm <= minBpm)
                bpm = minBpm;
            TextView bpmText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bps);
            bpmText.setText(""+bpm);
            metroTask.setBpm(bpm);
            minBpmGuard();
            return true;
        }

    };

    private OnSeekBarChangeListener volumeListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            volume = (short) progress;
            audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }       

    };

    private OnItemSelectedListener beatsSpinnerListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Beats beat = (Beats) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            TextView timeSignature = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timesignature);
            timeSignature.setText(""+beat+"/"+noteValue);
            metroTask.setBeat(beat.getNum());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };

    private OnItemSelectedListener noteValueSpinnerListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            NoteValues noteValue = (NoteValues) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            TextView timeSignature = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timesignature);
            timeSignature.setText(""+beats+"/"+noteValue);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
        SeekBar volumebar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.volumebar);
        volume = (short) audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        switch(keycode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN: 
                volumebar.setProgress(volume);
                break;                
        }

        return super.onKeyUp(keycode, e);
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        metroTask.stop();
//      metroTask = new MetronomeAsyncTask();
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, initialVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
        finish();    
    }

    private class MetronomeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
        Metronome metronome;

        MetronomeAsyncTask() {
            mHandler = getHandler();
            metronome = new Metronome(mHandler);
        }

        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            metronome.setBeat(beats);
            metronome.setNoteValue(noteValue);
            metronome.setBpm(bpm);
            metronome.setBeatSound(beatSound);
            metronome.setSound(sound);

            metronome.play();

            return null;            
        }

        public void stop() {
            metronome.stop();
            metronome = null;
        }

        public void setBpm(short bpm) {
            metronome.setBpm(bpm);
            metronome.calcSilence();
        }

        public void setBeat(short beat) {
            if(metronome != null)
                metronome.setBeat(beat);
        }

    }

}
```

I think there might be a problem with the 'private Handler getHandler' on line 48, but I have absolutely no clue how to solve this...

Edit: request to post the metronome-class:

```
package nl.ruudjanssenmusicservices.desaxofoonapp;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;

public class Metronome {

    private double bpm;
    private int beat;
    private int noteValue;
    private int silence;

    private double beatSound;
    private double sound;
    private final int tick = 1000; // samples of tick

    private boolean play = true;

    private AudioGenerator audioGenerator = new AudioGenerator(8000);
    private Handler mHandler;
    private double[] soundTickArray;
    private double[] soundTockArray;
    private double[] silenceSoundArray;
    private Message msg;
    private int currentBeat = 1;

    public Metronome(Handler handler) {
        audioGenerator.createPlayer();
        this.mHandler = handler;
    }

    public void calcSilence() {
        silence = (int) (((60/bpm)*8000)-tick);     
        soundTickArray = new double[this.tick]; 
        soundTockArray = new double[this.tick];
        silenceSoundArray = new double[this.silence];
        msg = new Message();
        msg.obj = ""+currentBeat;
        double[] tick = audioGenerator.getSineWave(this.tick, 8000, beatSound);
        double[] tock = audioGenerator.getSineWave(this.tick, 8000, sound);
        for(int i=0;i<this.tick;i++) {
            soundTickArray[i] = tick[i];
            soundTockArray[i] = tock[i];
        }
        for(int i=0;i<silence;i++)
            silenceSoundArray[i] = 0;
    }

    public void play() {
        calcSilence();
        do {
            msg = new Message();
            msg.obj = ""+currentBeat;
            if(currentBeat == 1)
                audioGenerator.writeSound(soundTockArray);
        //  else
            //  audioGenerator.writeSound(soundTickArray);              
            if(bpm <= 120)
                mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            audioGenerator.writeSound(silenceSoundArray);
            if(bpm > 120)
                mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            currentBeat++;
            if(currentBeat > beat)
                currentBeat = 1;
        } while(play);
    }

    public void stop() {
        play = false;
        audioGenerator.destroyAudioTrack();
    }

    public double getBpm() {
        return bpm;
    }

    public void setBpm(int bpm) {
        this.bpm = bpm;
    }

    public int getNoteValue() {
        return noteValue;
    }

    public void setNoteValue(int bpmetre) {
        this.noteValue = bpmetre;
    }

    public int getBeat() {
        return beat;
    }

    public void setBeat(int beat) {
        this.beat = beat;
    }

    public double getBeatSound() {
        return beatSound;
    }

    public void setBeatSound(double sound1) {
        this.beatSound = sound1;
    }

    public double getSound() {
        return sound;
    }

    public void setSound(double sound2) {
        this.sound = sound2;
    }

}
```

Comment: 54: `String message = (String)msg.obj;`

Comment: Can you also post the `Metronome` class please?

Comment: Looking at the code, it looks like the `play()` method runs in an infinite loop, continuously sending messages with no pauses in between. This will surely cause an out of memory error or slow down the responsiveness of the app.

Answer (score 0):

currentBeat is null there in onHandleMessage();