# Can't use static handler class because of "cannot referenced from a static context"

Tags: java, android, static

I'm writing a simple socket client app for android, here is my handler class:

```
static Handler IncomingHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (flag) {
            kq += msg.obj.toString() + "\r\n";
            textResponse.setText(kq);
        }
    }
};
```

This handler has a "should be static or leaks may occur" warning, and it did. It keeps running in a loop, using 40% CPU.

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407943/this-handler-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur-incominghandler), I changed my handler class to

```
static class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
    private final WeakReference<MainActivity> mService; 

    IncomingHandler(MainActivity service) {
        mService = new WeakReference<MainActivity>(service);
    }
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
         MainActivity service = mService.get();
         if (service != null) {
          if (flag) {
                kq += msg.obj.toString() + "\r\n";
                textResponse.setText(kq);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

It doesn't have "leaks may occur" warning anymore, but now a new problem appeared: I can't refer IncomingHandler from another class

```
public class ClientTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> implements
        OnListener {
////Some random code
    void sendMessage(String msg) {
        try {
                if (!msg.equals("bye"))
                MainActivity.IncomingHandler.obtainMessage(0, 0, -1, "Me: " + msg)
                        .sendToTarget();
            else
                MainActivity.IncomingHandler.obtainMessage(0, 0, -1,
                        "Disconnecting!").sendToTarget();
        } catch (Exception ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now it says "non-static method obtainMessage cannot be referenced from a static context”. But making IncomingHandler non-static makes the whole thing pointless. Is there anyway I can use obtainMessage from a static context?

EDIT1: I tried to add `static IncomingHandler incoming = new IncomingHandler(MainActivity.this);` and used `MainActivity.incoming.obtainMessage();` but it said "MainActivity.this cannot be referenced from a static context" so commenters' suggestions don't work for me.

EDIT2: I was dumb, I forgot to remove "MainActivity" from `MainActivity.incoming.obtainMessage()`. The problem is still there though.

Comment: I believe `obtainMessage` is not a static method, meaning you should create an instance of `MainActiviey.InComingHandler` and call `obtainMessage` on that object

Comment: You may be confusing the static nested class (meaning the handler isn't attached to a particular instance of the activity) with a static method (meaning you aren't working with any instance of the handler at all).

Comment: I created `static IncomingHandler incoming = new IncomingHandler(MainActivity.this);` and use `MainActivity.incoming.obtainMessage()` but they still show "MainActivity.this cannot be referenced from a static context" so i thought it wasn't the correct answer. If I change it to non-static then the obtainMessage method throws the same error.

Comment: Try `IncomingHandler incoming = new IncomingHandler(this);` and `incoming.obtainMessage()`.

Comment: I'd suggest you learn about Java to understand what it means to have a static field and a static class and what restrictions that implies.

Comment: @KNeerajLal can you make an answer with your comment? I will choose it as accepted answer.

Comment: @ProudNoob Check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object of `IncomingHandler` and call `obtainMessage()` on that object.

Try this code,

```
IncomingHandler incoming = new IncomingHandler(this);
incoming.obtainMessage();
```